# How to test the style inside the CSS class for React component using Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Consider in CSS,

```
.content
{
    width:500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I have added this css class inside react component as following

```
const Banner = () => {
   return (<div className="content">This is message content</div>);
}
```

How to write jest and enzyme test cases to ensure the **'box-sizing' with 'border-box'** applied properly?

*Notes: I can write the test case to ensure the ".content" class added to this element. But exactly, i need to write test case to ensure the value in 'box-sizing'.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to fix your issue, but keep in mind your test will not cover

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

if you will defined somewhere alse.

From my perspective, it does not make sense to test styles, because we can not guaranty from the test perspective that element will look like we want to. So still you will need to open the browser and check your element works properly, but you are writing tests to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this code to `Banner.test.js` file, it'll check if className called `content` have inline style property for `box-sizing` and is it equal to `border-box` or not. But it'll test only inline styles.

```
const banner = shallow(<Banner/>);
it("render propperely", () => {
expect(banner).toMatchSnapshot();
expect(banner.find(".content")
.get(0).props.style).toHaveProperty("box-sizing", "border-box");
  });
```

Comment: Please update your answer to provide context in plain english

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.